# How to make a model appear and disappear in animation?

Tags: modeling, animation

So I'm trying to make a model disappear when a certain time hits and replace it with a different object. Some of the answers were to use the transparency node but isn't there any simple solution for this rather than using node?

Comment: You can create some keyframes on the render option of the object, either in the Outliner or in the Object panel > Visibility

Comment: It is showing Error : "hide_viewport Property cannot be Animated".

Comment: You can't keyframe the visibility of the collection but you can do it for one object, or for a collection instance